# how to give timestamp in range query Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

In Elastic-search range query , timestamp is in this 2019-08-28T08:57:04.749Z formate, when execute the following query it throws a error  "Unrecognized chars at the end of [2019-08-28T08:57:04.749Z- 1h]. how  can we minus 1 hr in lte value?

```
  {
 "query": {
 "range" : {
    "@timestamp" : {
        "gte": "2015-03-20T01:21:00.01Z", 
        "lte": "2015-03-20T01:12:00.04Z-1h"

      }
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right way to do it is by adding a double pipe, like this:

```
{
 "query": {
 "range" : {
    "@timestamp" : {
        "gte": "2015-03-20T01:21:00.01Z", 
        "lte": "2015-03-20T01:12:00.04Z||-1h"

      }
   }
 }
```

However, you should note that your query won't return anything, because the to date is earlier than the from date.

Comment: i set the from date but stil no result

Comment: Can you tell which bounds you're now using and also show a document that you think should match?

Comment: hy im using this for running query , timestamp= 2015-03-20T01:21:00.01Z, var body = bodybuilder()
      .query("term", "beat.name", beatName)
      .query("range", "@timestamp", {
        gte: timestamp|| - "1h",
        lte: timestamp
      });

Comment: Try with `gte: timestamp - "||1h"`

Comment: didnt work, just console the query and this was output 
 { gte: '2019-08-28T08:57:04.749Z||1h',
   lte: '2019-08-28T08:57:04.749Z' }

Comment: Sorry, forgot the minus sign: `gte: timestamp + "||-1h"`

Comment: its ok but after console the query this is output
 { '@timestamp':
    { gte: '2019-08-28T08:57:04.749Z||-1h',
      lte: '2019-08-28T08:57:04.749Z' }

Comment: which is now correct, right? i.e. you'd get all documents from the past hour before `08:57:04.749Z`